# Double integral over the region enclosed by several lines

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

The question is:

> Calculate the double integral $$\iint_D (18x^2+51xy+30y^2)^2\,dx\,dy$$
>   where $D$ is an area enclosed by the following lines: 
>   $$6x+5y=9,\quad 6x+5y=-9,\quad 3x+6y=7, \quad 3x+6y=-7$$

I have tried doing it the following way but it's wrong and I can't seem to get it working.

```
NIntegrate[
 Boole[-9 <= 6 x + 5 y <= 9 && -7 <= 3 x + 6 y <= 7], 
 {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}
]
```

Comment: Use `Integrate` instead of `Integrate` to get exact answer; correct typo in `y`-domain so it runs from `-Infinity` at lower end!

Comment: @murray
I assume you meant Integrate instead of NIntegrate? if so, they both give the same output. and the typo is only here, used -infinity in the function. fixed it now

Comment: Yes, I meant `Integrate` instead of `NIntegrate` (typo was from Mac's "helpful" auto-correct).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since *Mathematica 10* there's been `ImplicitRegion`. We define that region this way:

```
IR = ImplicitRegion[-9 <= 6 x + 5 y <= 9 && -7 <= 3 x + 6 y <= 7, {x, y}];
```

then we can calculate this integral directly:

```
Integrate[(18 x^2 + 51 x*y + 30 y^2)^2, {x, y} ∈ IR]
```

> ```
> 5292
> ```

This integral can be calculated without the newest version of the system, to enlighten its structure we proceed in the following way:

```
18 x^2 + 51 x*y + 30 y^2 // Factor
```

> ```
> 3 (x + 2 y) (6 x + 5 y)
> ```

We change linearly variables: `w == 3x + 6y;  z == 6x + 5y;`. The Jacobian of this transformation  we calculate directly:

```
Det @ D[{3 x + 6 y, 6 x + 5 y}, {{x, y}}]
```

> ```
> -21
> ```

We take the absolute value of its inverse and the integral can be factorized, thus :

```
int = 1/21 Integrate[w^2 z^2, {w, -9, 9}, {z, -7, 7}]
```

> ```
>  5292
> ```

For completness we provide another two straightforward ways which work also in earlier versions of the system:

```
Integrate[ 
  Boole[-9 <= 6 x + 5 y <= 9 && -7 <= 3 x + 6 y <= 7] (18 x^2 + 51 x y + 30 y^2)^2,
  {x, -∞, ∞}, {y, -∞, ∞}]

Integrate[ 
  HeavisideTheta[6 x + 5 y + 9] HeavisideTheta[9 - 6 x - 5 y] 
  HeavisideTheta[3 x + 6 y + 7] HeavisideTheta[7 - 3 x - 6 y] 
   (18 x^2 + 51 x y + 30 y^2)^2, {x, -∞, ∞}, {y, -∞, ∞}]
```

Answer (score 3):

This post is cosmetic. It adds nothing to Artes excellent and instructive answer (which I have voted for). I post it to illustrate visualization of the region (a parallelogram in this instance) and use same change of variables as Artes. I think `SliceContourPlot3D` is also a a nice way to visualize.

```
m = {{6, 5}, {3, 6}};
mi = Inverse[m];
mi3 = ArrayFlatten[{{mi, 0}, {0, 1}}];
f[x_, y_] := Times @@ (m.{x, y})^2;
j = Abs[Det@D[m.{x, y}, {{x, y}}]];
cp = ContourPlot[
   Evaluate@Table[m.{x, y} == k {9, 7}, {k, {1, -1}}], {x, -5, 
    5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"];
pp = ParametricPlot[mi.{u, v}, {u, -9, 9}, {v, -7, 7}, 
   PlotStyle -> Yellow];
sh1 = Legended[Show[{cp, pp}], SwatchLegend[{Yellow}, {"Region D"}]];
reg = ParametricRegion[mi.{u, v}, {{u, -9, 9}, {v, -7, 7}}];
i1 = HoldForm[Integrate[a^2 b^2, {a, -9, 9}, {b, -7, 7}]/j];
i2 = HoldForm[Integrate[f[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] reg]];
p3 = Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] reg, Mesh -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.2]];
reg3 = ParametricRegion[
   mi3.{u, v, w}, {{u, -9, 9}, {v, -7, 7}, {w, 0, 1}}];
scp = SliceContourPlot3D[
   z - f[x, y], {z == 0}, {x, y, z} \[Element] reg3, 
   PlotPoints -> 100, Contours -> {0., -10, -100, -1000}];
sh2 = Show[p3, scp, ImageSize -> 300];
vr = ParametricRegion[
   mi3.{u, v, w}, {{u, -9, 9}, {v, -7, 7}, {w, 0, f @@ (mi.{u, v})}}];
vol = Volume[vr];
TraditionalForm@
 Grid[{{Row[{HoldForm@f[x, y], " = ", f[x, y], " = ", 
      Expand[Times @@ (m.{x, y})]^2}], SpanFromLeft}, {sh1, sh2}, 
   Row[{#, " = ", ReleaseHold@#}, BaseStyle -> {20}] & /@ {i1, 
     i2}, {Row[{"Parametric region D: ", vr[[1]]}], 
    Row[{"Volume of D = ", vol}]}}, Alignment -> Left, Frame -> All]
```

[image]