# Difficulty evaluating integral with Boole

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, warning-messages

I am trying to evaluate

```
Integrate[
 Integrate[
  Integrate[
   Integrate[
    Boole[x <= y + w + z], {w, 0, x}
    ]
   , {z, 0, x}
   ]
  , {y, 0, x}
  ]
 , {x, 0, 1}
 ]
```

When I run the code in *Mathematica 12.3.1* offline or *Wolfram Cloud* I get the answer as

> $\frac{5}{6}$Integrate`\$\$a\$7051$^3$

The number after the "a" changes every time.

How can I fix this?

Is this a bug?

Comment: Yes, it is a bug. Though as others have noted, there are better ways to do the computation, and reasons to expect this way will not work well. If you want to nest the integrals then assumptions about the outer variables should be made apparent to the inner integrals, like this. `In[417]:= Integrate[
 Integrate[
  Integrate[
   Integrate[Boole[x <= y + w + z], {w, 0, x}, 
    Assumptions -> {0 < z < x, 0 < y < x, 0 < x < 1}], {z, 0, x}, 
   Assumptions -> {0 < y < x, 0 < x < 1}], {y, 0, x}, 
  Assumptions -> {0 < x < 1}], {x, 0, 1}]

Out[417]= 5/24`

Answer (score 6):

It is enough to use a single  `Integrate` and to set  Integrationpart `x` outer most:

```
Integrate[Boole[x <= y + w + z], {x, 0, 1}, {w, 0, x} , {z, 0, x} , {y, 0, x} ] 
(*5/24*)
```

No bug!

Answer (score 4):

In the innermost integral  `Integrate[ Boole[x <= y + w + z], {w, 0, x}]` is purely symbolic since `Integrate` does not know what is `x` neither `y` and `z`, consequently `Boole` cannot be evaluated,  and at last there is an improper result. What is behind the scene can be noticed acting with `Trace` on the nested integrals. This seems to be rather an improper usage of `Integrate`, nonetheless there shouldn't appear such issues.

However if we are going to exploit `Boole` we have to calculate a multiple integral in an appropriate order:

```
Integrate[ Boole[x <= y + w + z], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, x}, {z, 0, x}, {w, 0, x}]
```

> ```
> 5/24
> ```

If one  necessarily needs  nested integrals then we have to supersede `Boole[x <= y + w + z]` with e.g. `UnitStep[y + w + z - x]` or `HeavisideTheta[y + w + z - x]`

```
Integrate[
  Integrate[
    Integrate[
      Integrate[ UnitStep[y + w + z - x], {w, 0, x}],
                                            {z, 0, x}], 
                                            {y, 0, x}], 
                                              {x, 0, 1}]
```

> ```
> 5/24
> ```

Nonetheless it takes much more time to evaluate, on my computer `AbsoluteTiming` is `15.2524`, however using `Integrate` once it takes `0.864271` while with `Boole` it is  `0.212867`, even worse timing with `HeavisideTheta`. There are instances where `HeavisideTheta` is more efficient than `Boole` e.g. [Double integral over the region enclosed by several lines](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/116311/double-integral-over-the-region-enclosed-by-several-lines/116315#116315)

Having said that it is remarkable to notice that **the most efficient way** seems to be one **using `ImplicitRegion`** (since version `10.0` of the system)

```
AbsoluteTiming[
  IR = ImplicitRegion[ x <= y + w + z && 0 <= x <= 1 && 
                       0 <= y <= x && 0 <= w <= x && 0 <= z <= x, {x, y, w, z}];
  Integrate[1, {x, y, w, z} ∈ IR]]
```

> ```
> {0.0102903, 5/24}
> ```

This ensures that the newer method if quite reliable unlike at the times when it just had appeared, see e.g. answers in [Finding length of intersection of two surfaces](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58768/finding-length-of-intersection-of-two-surfaces).